# Make filter on wpf Listbox with Item template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox in WPF databinded to a observablecollection

```
                        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ShopList}"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" KeyDown="ListBox_KeyDown" KeyUp="ListBox_KeyUp"
                             >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" >
                                    <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                                    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="6" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>

                                    <StackPanel Width="Auto">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I then have a filter method I want called

```
private void ShopItemDay_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Item as ShopItem;

        e.Accepted = item.Day == 1;
    }
```

But I cant find any properties on the Listbox to use a filter method like done here http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the article you linked to, the filter is not a property of the Control. It is a property of the CollectionViewSource which is a kind of wrapper around the collection. This wrapper allows for sorting, grouping and filtering.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a 'view' on your collection. See the documentation for [CollectionView.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx). The framework will create a default view for all bound collections. You can add a filter as follows:

```
ICollectionView _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
_customerView.Filter = CustomerFilter

private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
{
    Customer customer = item as Customer;
    return customer.Name.Contains( _filterString );
}
```

(From this [tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html));